# Merge function and duplicate column names in sources

Tags: r, merge

```
b[,17] <- merge(a, b, by = "Date", all.y = TRUE)[ ,"RegID"]
```

There is a RegID column in both a and b... which produces an error.

> ```
> "Error in `[.data.frame`(merge(a, b, by = "Date", all.y = TRUE),  : 
>   undefined columns selected"
> ```

I could change the name in "a", but believe that there is probably an override which can fix this issue.

Can someone give a quick assist?

Comment: Did you look at the data post-`merge` and before `[,"RegID"]`? That would likely have demonstrated that your names are now `RegID.x` and `RegID.y`.

Comment: (BTW: `b[,17] <- merge(...)` seems really odd to me ... replacing a column (or matrix plane) with a frame.)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to remove the 'RegID' in one of the datasets with (`setdiff`) and do the `merge` (assuming thee 'RegID' are the same in both datasets)

```
merge(a, b[setdiff(names(b), "RegID")], by = "Date", all.y = TRUE)[ ,"RegID"]
```

---

Programmatically, if there are multiple `intersect`ing columns, find it with `intersect` and remove the 'Date' from it

```
nm1 <- setdiff(intersect(names(a), names(b)), "Date")
merge(a, b[setdiff(names(b), nm1)], by "Date",
      all.y = TRUE)
```

Comment: I have no idea how that works/worked, but it worked. What exactly does setdiff do? Change the name temporarily? Can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: @dwdionis  it remove that element.  e.g. `v1 <- letters[1:4]; setdiff(v1, "a")`  thereby having only a single column in one of the datasets with the same column name.  if there are duplicate column names, by default `data.frame` and other tabular structures won't permit to have those remain as such.  Insteead it will add some suffix to add to avoid confusion.  You can also check `?make.unique` or `make.names`

Comment: Unless you are certain that `all(a$RegID == b$RegID)` (for rows in common), then this is silently discarding data. Without that, this answer is (imo) not what you should be doing. (If you're fine with dropping the data, then this works fine :-)

Comment: @ r2evans

I am actually just trying to move data from a to b while matching values by Date, like an excel vlookup. The dates in both columns will differ slightly. I just want what is in a to move to b, b will technically me empty at that point, but I want to keep names the same if possible.

Comment: Gotcha, sounds like this will work fine. One thought: reduce `b` to only include the merge-key and columns you need instead of dealing with it post-merge. For example, `merge(a, b[,c("Date","colA","colB")], ...)` is very declarative and will reduce the chance of issues.

Comment: akrun, I find it odd that `merge` itself has no problem with producing a frame with duplicate column names, see `merge(..., suffixes=c("",""))` (though it does warn about duplicate names).

Comment: @r2evans  yes it has `suffixes` part.  In general, I wouldn't opt for having duplicate column names in my data

Comment: @r2evans

merge(a, b[,c("Date","colA","colB")], ...)

This still produces the same error as my original code.

Comment: If you literally used my example (with names `"colA"` and `"colB"`), then I apologize for not being clear: use your actual real column names. If you did replace those with your actual (relevant) column names and see the error `undefined columns selected`, then something else is going on ... you should really include sample data then (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @r2evans

Yes, I used my own column names, of course.

Comment: Okay, just checking :-). I don't think we can help any more than this without a reproducible question. Can you *please* provide sample data? It might be sufficient to paste the output from `dput(head(a))` and `dput(head(b))` (limiting the columns if they're wide, making sure at least the key and 2-3 relevant columns are in each frame).

Comment: (And you'd be surprised, sometimes literal sample code is pasted and attempted without personalizing it. A mistake perhaps made by hasty-coders or much less frequently mis-understanding "noob" R users.)